# Data import from WHMCS to WHMCS

Tags: import, whmcs

My client using 5 WHMCS tool for 5 different web site, now he would like to merged 5 sites in to one. So I need to merge the data of Client, Products, Orders etc.

I mean import WHMCS database from another WHMCS database, the software has plugin to import from another software - http://docs.whmcs.com/Importing_Data but not from other WHMCS website.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can download a copy **WHMCS to WHMCS (Merge) Login Required**

WHMCS to WHMCS (Merge) Login Required
This script allows you to combine 2 separate WHMCS installations into one. NOTE: To merge both installations must be running the *EXACT* same version (ie. V4.5.2 to 5.0.1 will not work)

http://www.whmcs.com/members/downloads.php?action=displaycat&catid=2

Answer (score 0):

The latest import tool is actually published in the WHMCS Marketplace. You can see it here:

https://marketplace.whmcs.com/product/46

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can simply use the Navicat Premium to Merge the mysql database .
you can do it talbe by table , just use the Data Synchronism function . Only allow the Insert records . don't delete and update .
that will be working for you .
but if you have any password for the hosting or dedicated server , the password will not come to the new website , because it is encrypted